# Qt designer - generating UI dynamically / generating unique names?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtwidgets

I've recently started lerning Qt and I'm facing the following problem:

---

I want to create sth like a **chessboard** (empty, doesn't have to do anything for now) - I've drawn a simple interface, but in the middle I need to make a chessboard itself (let's say it will be made out of small *QTextBrowser*s).

The problem is that **the size of chessboard must be specified by user**. So, drawing 16 fields and giving them unique *objectNames* is easy, but I have no idea how to:

1. generate those fields 'dynamically'
2. generate unique names for them, so I **will be able to refer to them later in code** eg. *field_1_1, field_1_2, field_1_3*

---

Thans in advance,

Comment: Why do they need names?

Comment: Why not to use simple QTableView and it's row/column-index navigation? I did what you want here few years ago by using tableview and custom cells.

Comment: @Leon ... Maybe they do not have to :D  But I need to somehow be able to change them in code to use eg. setStyleSheet

Comment: If you gonna hardcode like that `field_1_1` I have bad news for you.. Explore the things and technologies that Qt provides and think twice what you need to achieve and what from Qt can help you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I think you want is a two-dimensional array of fields. That way you can reference the correct field without knowing the name.

More specifically Qt provides [QLayoutGrid](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html#itemAtPosition) which, although not a two dimensional array, will give you grid access to widgets by using the `itemAtPosition` method

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've created sth like You said. The thing is that itemAtPosition returns QLayoutItem, and my items are of type QTextBrowser, so is there a way to use their functions?

Comment: so QLayoutItem has a method `widget()`, you will have to type cast it though